# running xcode on a virtualbox with OSX

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, virtualbox

I want to play around with developing apps for OSX and iOS, just to see what i can learn. The problem is that i don't have a Mac or money to buy one. I was wondering if it is possible to try OSX on virtualBox and run xcode to develop and even, maybe, publish the apps.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is, but it's illegal. Why not just grab a Linux distro, [build the open toolchain](https://github.com/H2CO3/xchain-ios) and develop for Cydia?

Comment: Hmm didn't knew that existed, but i really wanted to try xcode to, maybe, one day, i get a Mac. Also, i would like to see the process of publishing an app on the apple store.
(but i might see more about this Cydia and toolchain)